# showing that $(\int f )(\int g) \geq 1$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu(X) =1$.
Let $f,g \in L^1(X)$ be two positive functions satisfying $f(x) g(x)>1$ for almost all $x$, Then $$\left(\int f ~dx\right) \left(\int g~dx\right) \geq 1.$$

Show also that if $f,g\in L^2(X)$ with $\int f ~dx= 0$, then  $$\left(\int fg~dx\right)^2 \leq \left[ \int g^2 ~dx - \left(\int g~dx\right)^2 \right] \int f^2~dx.$$

I think I have to use Holder's inequality for both questions:

For the first question, since $\mu(X) =1$, $1\lt \int fg~dx$. How do  I apply Holder's inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, try applying the inequality to $\int \sqrt{f g}$, and obtain a lower bound for $\int \sqrt{f g}$.

For the second, let $\overline{g} = \int g$, and apply the inequality to $\int f (g-\overline{g})$.

Comment: what do you mean by "apply the inequality?"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the square root. Apply the inequality to $\int \sqrt{fg} = \int \sqrt{f} \sqrt{g}$.

Comment: To apply Holder's inequality don't I need $f\in L^p$ and $g\in L^q$ where $p$ and $q$ are conjugates? The problem I have is that both $f,g\in L^1$.

Comment: Since $f \in L^1$, it follows that $\sqrt{f} \in L^2$. Similarly for $g$. The conjugate of 2 is 2.

Comment: Is there a general theory for that, because I'm not aware of it. Using that I get $$1\le \left[\int f \int g\right]^{1/2}.$$ right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to by 'that'. Anyway, square both sides of your inequality and you have your result.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was referring to $f\in L^1 \implies \sqrt{f} \in L^2$.

Comment: No general theory, just an observation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

For the first inequality use Hölder for $\sqrt{gf}$.

Comment: what will be the conjugate exponents?

Comment: @Daniel: 2 and 2.  In other words, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.